# How can I do a conditional search in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to make a conditional query.

I want to search in the whole collection those documents that fit in range of prices of 25% and if the documents has a particular field(in this case `'audiPrice'`) I will use this field to do my search, and if this document hasn't the field, I will use a `'price'` field.

I searched in the mongodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), found the operator `$cond` and I tried to make a the query as you can see:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$cond': {
            'if': {'audiPrice': {'$exists': True}}, 'then': {'$match':
                {'audiPrice': {
                    '$lte': price * 1.75, '$gte': price * 0.25
            }
                }
            },'else': {'$match': {
                'price': {
                    '$lte': price * 1.75, '$gte': price * 0.25
            }
            }


        }

    }
    }

]
```

and I got this error message:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$cond'
```

How could I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cond` in `$project` or `$expr` in `$match` stage as:

```
collectionName.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $gt: [
              "$audiPrice",
              null
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gte: [
                  "$audiPrice",
                  price * 0.25
                ]
              },
              {
                $lte: [
                  "$audiPrice",
                  price * 1.75
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          else: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gte: [
                  "$price",
                  price * 0.25
                ]
              },
              {
                $lte: [
                  "$price",
                  price * 1.75
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here you first check if field audiPrice is not null then perform the match on that key else on price key.