# Mongodb (pymongo) - Group data by field and get only those elements where length of grouped field > 1

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have task to group data by field and get only those elements where length of grouped elements > 1.

Data example:

```
{
'pid': 123456789,
'price': 55
},
{
'pid': 123456789,
'price': 25
},
{
'pid': 123456700,
'price': 10
}
```

I'm grouping by id and price like so

```
qf = [
   {'$group': {
    '_id': '$pid',
    'prices': {'$addToSet': '$price'}
   }}
]
table.aggregate(qf)
```

**Current result**:

```
{
'123456789': [55, 25],
'123456700': [10]
}
```

**What I'm trying to get**:

```
{
'123456789': [55, 25]  # only data with 2 elements in a list!
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$size`

```
{
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          { $size: "$prices"},
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TTzUdLB8EoL)**

Comment: your solution is perfect but i think he needed > 1 as per his title, just need to change $eq ot $gte

Comment: thank you @varman! is there a way to do it w/o 'expr', I'm getting 'OperationFailure' unknown top operator: $expr'

Comment: @venv $expr is a operation of mongodb.. I'm still excited how does pymongo throw an error. I will research an let u know.

Comment: @venv as I know most of the pymongo devs uses `$expr` without any problem. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53595559/7975771 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/58099645/7975771